# static expressions for method chaining C++

Tags: c++, static, c++14, method-chaining

I'm implementing a parser library and would like the user to define parsers via method chaining. However when defined via method chaining in a header file, and then called in `.cpp` it will return segmentation fault because the intermediate results are not static. If I were to split them up each into static variables it works.

Is there a workaround to still be able to define my parsers via method chaining without this verbosity?

```
static Parser<int> term1 = binop_add.alt(binop_sub).map<int>(int_of_either_ints);
// segmentation fault

static Parser<Either<int,int>> term1_alt = binop_add.alt(binop_sub);
static Parser<int> term1 = term1_alt.map<int>(int_of_either_ints);
// works fine
```

Here the result of calling `alt` generates an intermediate parser which is then chained with `map` to make yet another parser. Chaining them directly causes segmentation fault when I call the actual parse method on it as the intermediate parsers have gone out of scoped and gced i assume.

Edit:
I'm thinking of using `constexpr` but my definition of `Parser` involves `std::string` and `std::function` which makes it not viable.

Comment: C++ does not have garbage collection (you said "gced I assume").  Post complete code or this isn't a valid question.

Comment: Could you supply a some more code? Would be nice to have something to play around with like a project on an online compiler like [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/) or [OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)... In particular OnlineGDB is nice for code involving headers and source files. Something like a minimal working example of the underlying functions would be nice...

Comment: temporaries are destroyed at the end of the expression. Its not clear how your solution fixes it, and without a [mcve] we don't know what you want to fix

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by changing my parser combinators to return `new Parser<...>(...)` and used pointers to compose parsers instead of values.

AFTER:

```
Parser<Either<T, U>>* alt(std::string l, const Parser<U> *b) const
  {
    return new
    Parser<Either<T, U> >(l, [&, b](State &s) {
      State _s = s;
      try
      {
        return Left<T, U>(parse(s));
      }
      catch (std::vector<State> e)
      {
        return Right<T, U>(b->parse(_s));
      }
    });
  }
```

BEFORE:

```
Parser<Either<T, U>> alt(std::string l, Parser<U> b) const
  {
    return Parser<Either<T, U> >(l, [&, b](State &s) {
      State _s = s;
      try
      {
        return Left<T, U>(parse(s));
      }
      catch (std::vector<State> e)
      {
        return Right<T, U>(b.parse(_s));
      }
    });
  }
```

The working method chaining now looks like this

```
static Parser<int>* term1 = binop_add->alt("term1", binop_sub)->map<int>(int_of_either_ints);
```

Comment: That's just begging for memory leaks. Use a smart pointer at the very least.